# I want to host a nextjs website in shared hosting. Which is the best way?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hosting

I want to make a website using nextjs. I want to know what is the best way to host it without hurting seo. Let's say that my domain is 'www.myDomain.com'

I have domain on my shared hosting. I can

1. host nextjs app in vercel and point to the domain in my shared hosting
2. copy nextjs build folder to shared hosting

Website should be rendered on server and come to the client unlike react which loads content on the clients browser. It is important for seo.

does the second option(copying build folder) renders on server or it works like a react app that load all the content on clients browser?

Comment: Shared hosting usually does not support node based frontend frameworks. So, youll need to host your site on vercel

Comment: then what is the next build folder for?

Comment: The build folder contains all the chunks of JS and all the pre generated html pages which requires `npm run start` command to run properly. They wont work like the old HTML+PHP used to work..

Comment: `npm run start` basically starts a nextjs server which serves these files correctly per requests...

Answer (score 1):

Next.js by default pre-renders html unless you opt for client side rendering logic. So no matter where you host, it's based on your choice of rendering.
Client side rendering is not best for SEO.

As for hosting,
If your shared hosting supports nodejs you can host your site there itself otherwise hosting on vercel is your best option.

- Just copying build won't work as you will need to run `npm run start` to start your next server